# If f is surjective then f is not a right divisor of zero

Tags: ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ a $R$-module. For $r\in R$ define $f:M\to M$ by $f(s)=sr$.
Show that $f$ is injective if and only if $r$ is not a right zero divisor.

I have done a similar problem to this in the past, involving surjectivity instead of injectivity and came up with:
Suppose $f$ is surjective and $gf=0$. To prove $f$ is not a right divisor of zero, we need to show that $g=0$, i.e. that $g(m)=0$ for all $m$. So let $m$ be in $M$. Since $f$ is surjective, $m=f(n)$ for some n in $M$. Thus $g(m)=g(f(n))=(gf)(n)=0(n)=0$.

However I am stuck with how to show this problem using injectivity, and was wondering could anybody provide guidance on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is injective *if and only if*

$f(s)=0  \Rightarrow s=0$ *if and only if*
$sr=0  \Rightarrow s=0$  *if and only if*

$r$ is not a right zero divisor.

Comment: Of course. I was making this out to be more complicated than it was. Is the other way of the proof something as simple?

Comment: edited: *iff* is a abbreviation for *if and only if*